# copy certain column values from one table to anther

Tags: mysql

In both tables I have a column named `date` (datetime - current timestamp).
I need to copy the first 20 values of that column from table `posts` to table `banners`.

```
insert into banners set date SELECT date FROM posts WHERE id < 21;
update banners set date SELECT date FROM posts WHERE id < 21;
```

In both cases I have an error:
`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

What does it mean this error and how I can copy the values?

Comment: You want to insert new rows or updated existing column in `banners` table?

Comment: better to use plsql instead of direct sql query

Comment: @Ullas, I need to update existing column in `banners`. Curently this is empty column, but it exists.

Comment: @bonaca : Is `id` column in `banners` table?

Comment: @Ullas, yes there is `id` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` with `UPDATE`.

**Query**

```
update `banners` t1
from `posts` t2
on t1.`id` = t2.`id`
set t1.`date` = t2.`date`
where t2.`id` < 21;
```